# Код стандартного метода или класса в .NET

Tags: c#, .net

Можно ли посмотреть, как реализован тот или иной стандартный метод или класс в .NET?

Например, я использую ArrayList и мне хочется видеть исходный код реализации, чтобы лучше понимать, как он устроен. Желательно, чтобы можно было сразу из IDE это видеть.

Comment: Воспользуйтесь Reflector или [dotPeek](http://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У ReSharper и Reflector есть соответствующие плагины для Visual Studio

Answer (score 2):

На текущий момент (2015 год) вы можете посмотреть все исходники на http://referencesource.microsoft.com. Например, для `ArrayList` это [здесь](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/arraylist.cs,30).

---

Кстати, имеет смысл отказаться от нетипизированных контейнеров наподобие `ArrayList` и перейти на `List<T>`.